# What is the meaning of readClosed in dart

Tags: sockets, dart

What is the meaning of readclosed in dart, the meaning of read and closed is obvious, then what does readclosed mean, when will it be used?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EdBl.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can recive that `RawSocketEvent` when the '[shutdown](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-io/RawSocket/shutdown.html)' method is called on the `RawSocket` class

> Shutdown the socket in the direction. Calling shutdown will never
>   throw an exception and calling it several times is supported. Calling
>   shutdown with either SocketDirection.both or SocketDirection.receive
>   can result in a RawSocketEvent.readClosed event.

or simply when the connection with the Socket is closed.